# Is there a limit on the size of the data returned from EF CORE 3.1 queries?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a `.NetCore 3.1` web application built on `EF CORE 3.1` that is connected to a `SQL Server 2017`.
When I run a certain query directly through SSMS against the DB it returns ~630000 records which is correct.
However when the same query is run through the web app through

```
return await _MyDBContext.myDBSet.FromSqlRaw(query).ToListAsync();
```

it only returns 50479 records. This max number is fixed for all use cases. (i.e. when I have ~61000 records from a direct query to the DB, EF Core still returns 50479 records.) Of course, if the query is expected to return a lower number than 50479, I get the correct number of records.

**Is there a limit on the number of data rows returned from EF Core queries? (Or a limit on the size of the data?) If yes, how can I disable/change it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the root cause! It was the default capacity on the List that holds the output of

```
 return _MyDBContext.myDBSet.FromSqlRaw(query).ToListAsync();
```

I modified my code to be:

```
List<MyRecordType> retList = new List<MyRecordType>(2000000);
retList = await _MyDBContext.myDBSet.FromSqlRaw(query).ToListAsync();
return retList;
```

and it fixed the issue!

Comment: I'm not sure how this fixes an issue, but the list returned from `ToListAsync` is not the same list that you set to `retList` with `new` statement, it is a new one created by the EF. Looks like some strange sideeffect which is  not guaranteed to work in later versions.